# Twilio call and work accordingly with response from customer

Tags: php, xml, twilio

I am using Twilio API. My requirement is call to a customer.
1. After receiving the call by customer will hear some text message. The text message will be like this "Press 1 to call client press 2 to call helpline press 3 to listen the message again and etc".
I can do this separately. I can receive that key which is pressed by customer by "Gather tag. But I can not do further.

Below is the code

```
$call = $client->account->calls->create($number, $sender_number, 'http://www.mysiteurl.com/outbound.xml', array(
    "Method" => "GET",
    "StatusCallback" => "http://www.mysiteurl.com/outbound.xml",
    "StatusCallbackMethod" => "POST",
    "StatusCallbackEvent" => array("initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed"),
   ));
```

In outbound.xml

```
<=Response=>
    <=Gather action="http://www.mysiteurl.com/outbound.php" method="GET" timeout="20"=>
    <=Say=>Press 1 to dial the customer's phone number. Press 2 to dial support hotline. Press 3 to listen the message again.</Say>
    <=/Gather=>
<=/Response=>
```

In outbound.php

```
$AccountSid     = "XXXXX";
$AuthToken      = "YYY";

$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

$response = $_REQUEST['Digits'];

if($response == 1)
{
    $call = $client->account->calls->create($number, $sender_number, 'http://www.mysiteurl.com/one.xml', array(
    "Method" => "GET",
    "StatusCallback" => "http://www.mysiteurl.com/test.php",
    "StatusCallbackMethod" => "POST",
    "StatusCallbackEvent" => array("initiated", "ringing", "answered",  "completed"),
    ));

}
```

In one.xml

```
<=Response=>
    <=Dial=>+1234567890<=/Dial=>
    <=Say=>Thank you for calling the customer. Hope you enjoy the call. Goodbye<=/Say=>
<=/Response=>
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's a couple of things here.

My bet, though I don't know exactly, is that $_REQUEST['Digits'] will return a string rather than a number. So I would change your conditional to check for `$response == "1"`.

In order to dial the caller onto another number you don't actually need to use the REST API, you can just return the TwiML needed to make the dial. So your outbound.php could look like this:

```
<?php
  $AccountSid     = "XXXXX";
  $AuthToken      = "YYY";

  $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

  $response = $_REQUEST['Digits'];

  if($response == "1") {
        header("content-type: text/xml");
        echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
        ?>
        <Response>
          <Dial><Number><?php echo $number; ?></Number></Dial>
        </Response>
        <?php
  }
?>
```

That will forward the caller onto `$number`.